# Mi programa en C no ejecuta nada (lista enlazadas dobles)

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

No soy entusiasta de C, pero hago esto para mi tarea sobre listas enlazadas dobles que pide las funciones principales (insertar nodos, borrar nodos, etc).
Probando cada función por separado (insertar_inicio, insertar_final), funcionan sin  problemas. Es cuando coloco la ejecución de `insertar_inicio` antes de `insertar_final` en el main que al ejecutar el programa no hay nada en la consola. Compila, pero no ejecuta nada.
Cuando coloco la ejecución de `insertar_final` antes de `insertar_inicio`, el programa ejecuta sin problemas.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// estructura de un Nodo
struct Nodo 
{ 
    int dato;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
    struct Nodo *anterior;
};

// Se inicializa la lista globalmente
typedef struct Nodo *nodo;
nodo cabeza = NULL;

// Prototipos
void insertar_inicio(nodo*, int);
void insertar_final(nodo*, int);
void imprimir(nodo);

int main()
{
    //insertar_inicio(&cabeza, 1);
    //insertar_inicio(&cabeza, 2);
    insertar_inicio(&cabeza, 3);
    
    insertar_final(&cabeza, 9);
    insertar_final(&cabeza, 1);
    
    imprimir(cabeza);
    
    return 0;
}

void insertar_inicio(nodo *cabeza, int dato)
{
    // Se crea un nuevo nodo
    struct Nodo *nuevoNodo = (struct Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));

    // corroborar si hay espacio disponible
    if (nuevoNodo != NULL) {
        nuevoNodo->dato = dato; // se ingresa el dato al nodo
        nuevoNodo->siguiente = *cabeza; // el nuevo nodo apunta a la cabeza
        nuevoNodo->anterior = NULL; // el nuevo nodo no tiene anterior
        
        // Corroborar si la lista ya tiene elementos
        if(*cabeza != NULL)
            (*cabeza)->anterior = nuevoNodo; // el nuevo nodo se pone a la izq de la cabeza
        
        // el nuevo nodo es la nueva cabeza
        *cabeza = nuevoNodo;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d no se inserto. Memoria no disponible.\n", dato);
    }
}

void insertar_final(nodo *cabeza, int dato)
{
    // Se crea un nuevo nodo
    struct Nodo *nuevoNodo = (struct Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));

    // Nodo de apoyo temporal
    struct Nodo *temp;

    // Corroborar si hay espacio disponible
    if (nuevoNodo != NULL) {
        nuevoNodo->dato = dato; // insertar el dato en el nodo

        // Corroborar si la lista esta vacia
        if (*cabeza != NULL)
        {
            temp = *cabeza; //el nodo temporal inicia en la cabeza

            // Recorrer la lista 
            while (temp->siguiente != NULL) {
                temp->siguiente = temp;
            }
            
            // El nuevo nodo se coloca despues del ultimo elemento de la lista actual
            nuevoNodo->anterior = temp; 
            temp->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
            nuevoNodo->siguiente = NULL;
        }
        else {
            nuevoNodo->siguiente = NULL;
            nuevoNodo->anterior = NULL;
            *cabeza = nuevoNodo;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("%d no se inserto. Memoria no disponible.\n", dato);
    }
}

void imprimir(nodo cabeza)
{
    printf("\nLista: \n");

    while (cabeza != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", cabeza->dato);
        cabeza = cabeza->siguiente;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un fallo en `insertar_final` que como da el resultado esperado al no combinarla con `insertar_inicio` aparenta que funciona bien.

El while está mal. Es:

```
while (temp->siguiente != NULL) {
    temp = temp->siguiente;
}
```

Con eso ya está resuelto.

---

Ya que tienes una lista doblemente enlaza podrías guardar el último nodo en una variable. Así tendrías `cabeza` y `cola` por ejemplo.

La ventaja de hacer esto es que no tienes que recorrer todo el arreglo para agregar un elemento al final.

El código se vería así:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Declaración de Nodo con typedef para
// poder usar simplemente Nodo en la definición 
typedef struct Nodo Nodo;

// Estructura de un Nodo
struct Nodo 
{ 
    int dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
    Nodo *anterior;
};

typedef struct Lista {
    Nodo* inicio;
    Nodo* final;
} Lista;

Lista lista;

// Prototipos
void iniciar_lista(Lista*);
void insertar_inicio(Lista*, int);
void insertar_final(Lista*, int);
void imprimir(Lista);

int main()
{
    iniciar_lista(&lista);
    //insertar_inicio(&lista, 1);
    //insertar_inicio(&lista, 2);
    insertar_inicio(&lista, 3);
    
    insertar_final(&lista, 9);
    insertar_final(&lista, 1);
    
    imprimir(lista);
    
    return 0;
}

void insertar_inicio(Lista* lista, int dato)
{
    if (lista == NULL) return;

    // Se crea un nuevo nodo
    Nodo* nuevoNodo =  malloc(sizeof(Nodo));

    // Corroborar si hay espacio disponible
    if (nuevoNodo != NULL) {
        nuevoNodo->dato = dato;
        nuevoNodo->siguiente = lista->inicio;
        nuevoNodo->anterior = NULL;
        
        // Corroborar si la lista ya tiene elementos
        if(lista->inicio != NULL)
            lista->inicio->anterior = nuevoNodo;
       
        if(lista->final == NULL)
            lista->final = nuevoNodo;
        
        lista->inicio = nuevoNodo;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d no se insertó. Memoria no disponible.\n", dato);
    }
}

void insertar_final(Lista* lista, int dato)
{
    if (lista == NULL) return;

    // Se crea un nuevo nodo
    Nodo* nuevoNodo =  malloc(sizeof(Nodo));

    // Corroborar si hay espacio disponible
    if (nuevoNodo != NULL) {
        nuevoNodo->dato = dato;
        nuevoNodo->anterior = lista->final;
        nuevoNodo->siguiente = NULL;
        
        // Corroborar si la lista ya tiene elementos
        if(lista->final != NULL)
            lista->final->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
        
        if(lista->inicio == NULL)
            lista->inicio = nuevoNodo;
        
        lista->final = nuevoNodo;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d no se insertó. Memoria no disponible.\n", dato);
    }
}

void imprimir(Lista lista)
{
    printf("\nLista: \n");

    Nodo* cabeza = lista.inicio;
    while (cabeza != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", cabeza->dato);
        cabeza = cabeza->siguiente;
    }
}

void iniciar_lista(Lista* lista){
    lista->inicio = lista->final = NULL;
}
```

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##7VZLbtswFNzrFC8pWsiGP027al1703bnBgWC7gIUtETFBGhSoKgUjuFT5Qg5mPv4kyjZibvJrloIFmc478N5krNxxom4OxzeMJHxOqdfKp0zOVkvkniFs5VZSqZT@EZxhyIZe3oUkFO4lrmETArQ25LmtIASUUMsZU4V1BVRULFNyemGCu35VAAnuLtgglmlJOyutKoz7VjmNrNBv7vlWplNUAsLJTE32UECeDGhISca95knCw0rdlczEzxeJPismFSzZI8xeuGXrNIEdg19CDbRSHUImDvhuNuRUcNt4v4Js/6ppJaalbJK7iXLnQZRvy0ltfThYBawiiqNoAvk0ZGp54hiI59kbErFNkw5DFcT044NYSIdJDvfnziHd9wTDTSd9pNw8AiuzjI@eMZz@EePd0mukMD51NfowlcdiVBpXIC9KYo2EfAeTyZ5qbXgZYNhmgYV4ERhPofrX8vlwEtiN10P4IZCpigxPhQ1vZcgjBtbZ9hF67I5YPc5l1lasQcqizSy7GDQKn6VSsmVVHZWYE22QKsSZ0xCzqpSCrbitMmulb8IGbrUzdWA44WpCjNop6GHN2OBJFvxeBG7vMcO8wIuZstpfhzVwf00wJaAxkgUqHsL4ECETaxIO7GbmhqGuTqUTi5Nhk1CJ6StkZrzPKXsGSfkWr1unkfcvb1TXtHoONClQhfp5dscTQIIOTM@PU7gB91IxYhZbw95cisuR86PQfXIxvH4/3dx5IX4LM86/nVM7Hx0cc5p3VReMt3RfMzPzse/2fgZx7@6izufKJdMMG0Icyss@BlQJtjLeTIjK/pAwlFP4tfVnzXjFFLPOOGpqAhMzvGcvQZtl5oAAe/9d4jH8fhj7stxMftn0uu789/@cPgL).